# Ebean Search where ManyToMany is empty?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

With PlayFramework I'm trying to list all the items where there is no ManyToMany items associated with my model, how can I do that ?

Here's my structure :

```
User
    @ManyToMany
    List<Section> sections;

    public static Model.Finder<Long,User> find = new Model.Finder<Long, User>(Long.class, User.class);

Section
    Integer year;
    @ManyToMany
    List<User> users;

    public static Model.Finder<Long,Section> find = new Model.Finder<Long, Section>(Long.class, Section.class);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
String q="find * fetch sections where sections.id is null"

Ebean.createQuery(User.class,q).findList();
```

This will create a left outer join query, the find.where().IsNull("sections") doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

```
find.where().eq("sections", null).findList();
```

or

```
find.where().isNull("sections").findList();
```

Sorry it's from top of my head, can't verify it now.

Comment: Ok both works. But then, how can I found those that have ManyToMany ? I tried the opposite (`ne()` / `isNotNull()`) but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Weird, `find.where().isNotNull("sections").findList();` works for me (now I've checked it), try to enable SQL statement logging and check prepared queries, maybe there is some other constraint, which avoids selecting proper rows

Comment: From what I see, it's because Ebean join with "JOIN", if I add "LEFT JOIN", it works correctly. If not, it doesn't work :/

Comment: Well, I just found out something weirder : it works for `isNotNull`, but not for `isNull` (I spoke too quick)

Comment: To be more precise : `User.find.where().isNull("sections").findRowCount()` === 0 (but I have some users that doesn't have any sections!

Comment: Check my answer, if you do it using the Ebean query language you generate a left outer join query and that works.

Comment: this one doesnt work , @MiguelA.Carrasco one is working , tried out on Play 2.4.x